# Set Highcharts plot area margin

Tags: highcharts

Can I control the white space height in the graph below? I want to make it smaller.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

use this :

```
 yAxis: {
    tickPixelInterval: 10 ,// whatever you want
    maxPadding:0
}
```

**Additionally** if you want your chart to use full container space , use

```
chart:{
    spacingTop: 0,
    spacingLeft: 0,
    spacingRight: 0,
    spacingBottom: 0,
    margin:0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This spacing can depend on a number of factors.

In the case of your chart, I am guessing that your triangle marker is set with a value greater than 0, which will push the axis up to the next tick (in your case, 20,000).

If I try a similar set up, with the scatter point at `y` value of `0`, it does not extend the axis:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/90/

If I make the `y` value `1`, OTOH, it does extend the axis:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/91/

If I keep the `y` value of 1, and set the `maxPadding` to `0`, it has no effect (nor should it), and the axis still extends:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/92/

If I keep the y value of 1, set the `maxPadding` to 0, and set the `endOnTick` property to `false`, it works as desired again:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/93/

So the specific solution depends on your exact set up and desired result.